# F# - Http.RequestString Error - CURL And PowerShell OK

Tags: powershell, curl, f#-data

I am trying to access a remote service using "F# Data Http Utilities" but without success:

```
let account token = Http.RequestString("https://api.example.com/v1", 
                                       httpMethod = "POST",
                                       headers    = ["Accept", "application/json";
                                                     "Content-Type", "application/json"; 
                                                     "X-Application", "JRQ"; 
                                                     "X-Authentication", "MOl5C9ZZ";],
                                       body       = TextRequest """ {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "getAccount"} """)
```

even though both the curl and PowerShell equivalents work correctly:

```
curl -i -X POST \
   -H "Accept:application/json" \
   -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
   -H "X-Application:JRQ" \
   -H "X-Authentication:MOl5C9ZZ" \
   -d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "getAccount"}' \
'https://api.example.com/v1'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What error are you getting? Could it have to do with the lack of quotes around the URL?

Comment: Fyodor, my error in the example above for not including the quotes, but that is not the problem with the F# code. I get a 400 response from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no error in the original F# code. Setting the following property:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue <- false;
```

resolved the problem!